# Is $|2^\omega \cap L| = |(\omega_1)^L|$?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Is $|2^\omega \cap L| = |(\omega_1)^L|$?  Here I mean the set of all subsets of $\omega$ by $2^\omega$, but I hope that choosing that particular interpretation does not really matter here, as always.

Here is my tentative argument in favor of the equality: since $(\mathrm{GCH})^L$, we have $(|2^\omega| = \omega_1)^L$, which means $(\exists f : 2^\omega \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} \omega_1)$.  This implies $\exists f \in L$ $(f : 2^\omega \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} \omega_1)$.  For such $f$ (this is where things get murky to me) $f : (2^\omega)^L \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} (\omega_1)^L$, and since $(2^\omega)^L = 2^\omega \cap L$, we get $|2^\omega| = |(\omega_1)^L|$.

My argument has problems.  For one thing, I do not even know what I exactly mean by $(2^\omega)^L$.  One possible source of the problems is that I am not reasoning in terms of principles, but at the same time I do not think set theorists always think in terms of explicit sentences in the language $L(\in)$.

Does the equality hold?  What is the right attitude to reason about this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we write $(2^\omega)^L$ we mean the set $A$ in $L$, such that $L\models x\in A\leftrightarrow x\subseteq\omega$. It is the power set of $\omega$ as computed in $L$.

It is not hard to see why $2^\omega\cap L$ is indeed $(2^\omega)^L$, and therefore the rest of the argument follows immediately.

Comment: So $(2^\omega)^L$ is part of the standard notation, right?  I was confused with this equality since that trivializes a lengthy argument in a textbook (which assumed GCH in L).

Comment: Yes. It means "relativize the formula $2^\omega$ to $L$", or as I said "compute the formula in $L$". (And since GCH holds in $L$, this is not really an assumption, just to point out this issue.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  As for GCH, given that in a textbook the author might want to assume less for a pedagogical reason, I just wanted to point out that that was not the case in this particular argument in this particular textbook.